# Locale ES_PE is not rendering number properly

Tags: java, jvm, locale

[Locale planet](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/es-PE/index.html) specified that the es_PE locale should use "." for decimal and "," for grouping. But when I run this unit test on the Oracle JVM it fails:

```
public class TestLocale extends TestCase {

   public void test() {
       Locale locale = new Locale("es", "PE");
       DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(locale);

       assertEquals('.', decimalFormatSymbols.getDecimalSeparator());
       assertEquals(',', decimalFormatSymbols.getGroupingSeparator());

   }
}
```

And it was reported by our support staff that numbers are no rendering correctly on WAS 8 either.

Any idea how to fix this at the JVM level? Do I need to juggle the locale management code in the application for this special case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Locale locale = new Locale("es", "PE");
```

to

```
Locale locale = new Locale("es_PE");
```

By the way, PE is from Peru (where I'm from).

Comment: ok that was..unexpected, but it kind of make sense. Thanks :) (and I know Peru, being from Venezuela myself: it has one the best food I have ever eaten)

Comment: Although it produces the desired results, this is not correct. `new Locale("es", "PE")` is the right way. If you use "es_PE" you're really saying "Spanish variant PE in an undefined country". For some reason Java is using '.' as the grouping separator and ',' as the decimal separator, but for Peru it seems they should be the other way around. I couldn't find anything to confirm this, but I'm going to assume this is Java's mistake.